# Upgrading selenium 2.40 to 3.141.59 got error

Tags: selenium, selenium-grid

I am trying to upgrade my selenium 2.40 to 3.141. I am running below command

```
gridconfig.loadFromCommandLine(cmd);
```

got error the method `loadFromCommandLine(String[]) is undefined` for the type `GridHubConfiguration` when  I am trying to upgrade `selenium 2.42.0 to selenium 3.141.59`

Comment: are you trying to update selenium using command line?

Comment: no i  am trying to ubgrade selenium using  remove old jars and add new jars  in project so there is one method in which i am trying to start a node in which i am trying to call loadfromcommandline so its give me error